# How to mount Core Storage volume under Linux (or force conversion on unrevertible volume)?

Tags: mount, core-storage, hfs+, diskutil

I tried to mount HFS+ partition in Linux today, but I had problem with

```
hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

I've found later that this partition is in fact Core Storage container for the logical volume, what could mean I should at least know corrected offset of the real logical volume on this partition.

I tried to follow advices seen in plenty of places to revert the volume using `diskutil cs revert UUID`, however my problem is that I see:

```
Logical Volume C4FE8...
-----------------------------------------------------
[...]
Revertible:      No
[...]
```

Logical Volume Family above this has all encryption related fields set to *No*/*None*. However I cannot find a way how to have this volume revertible.

Because it's only 300 GB of data on 1TB drive, I've managed to shrink it. The idea I have is to create empty partition of the same size as the volume and the copy it using `dd`. Then I would have pure HFS+ partition probably mountable under Linux. However `gpt` in recovery doesn't allow me to add next partition to disk0 saying "resource is busy". Graphical utility seem to have some bug and I cannot confirm new partition (in recovery mode as I don't know the password to superuser account).

Now, does anyone manage to mount Core Storage volume at least read-only under Linux?
Or maybe someone found the way how to make this Core Storage volume revertible?

Comment: How far did you get ?
I'm stuck on a message saying `libfvde_io_handle_read_volume_header: unsupported core storage signature
`
Using the fvdemount from an Ubuntu Iso
I would also be happy with just read-only, maybe we can help each other ?

Comment: @oneindelijk I don't remember if I solved it at all. I think I surrendered and mount the drive using tools I found for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to remove CoreStorage entirely once a disk's been converted, but it is possible to [mount the HFS volumes](https://superuser.com/a/1088110/148367) inside (provided they are not encrypted - if so, you'll also need to use [libfvde](https://github.com/libyal/libfvde/wiki/Mounting)).